# Como atualizar a tabela (bootstrap-table) via JS após a realização de cadastro?

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Depois de realizar o cadastro (dentro de um modal), a tabela deve ser atualizada automaticamente. Mas não estou conseguindo.
OBS.: Linguagens que estou usando é o PHP e JS.

No jsfiddle, está uma pequena demonstração, na aba JS está o código (else) que estou tentando fazer para atualizar a query do bootstrap-table.

https://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/yydc9nv0/23/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar ajax:

```
$("#adicionar").click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'adicionar.php',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $(".table").append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**#adicionar** -> O id de um botão que devera ser incluindo para executar a ação

**Type** -> Método de envio das informações

**URL** -> A função feita em php que sera responsavel por incluir na sua tabela

**.Table** -> a classe da tabela onde sera enviado o resultado da função anterior

Para mostrar as informações você pode usar um `echo` mesmo, aí vai de você.

Answer (score 1):

Hei!

Vi no jsfiddle que você está montando a table com while.. acho que vale a pena mudar e deixar o próprio, bootstra-table montar a a table pra você, é simples:

Crie um arquivo PHP que retorna um json com os dados da table, e jogue o caminho desse arquivo dentro do atributo data-url, na tag table, fica assim:

```
> <table id="table-nome"
>   data-url="caminho_data.php"
> >
> <thead>
>   <tr>
>       <th data-field="campo1">Campo 1</th>
>       <th data-field="campo 2">Campo 2</th>
>   </tr>
> </thead>
> </table>
```

Ai, após gravar a informação no seu modal, no retorno do ajax, basta chamar:

```
$("#table-nome").bootstrapTable('refresh');
```

Você pode ver um exemplo aqui:

[http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/refresh.html][1]

Tem vários outros exemplos nesse site, dá uma olhada, o bootstrap-table tem muita funcionalidade legal que facilita muito a vida depois que a gente pega o jeito ;)

o/

Outra solução, GAMBIS ao meu ver, é jogar a table em outro arquivo e chamar esse arquivo de novo no retorno do ajax da ação do modal, e substituir a table atual...

Comment: Não sei pq negativaram a resposta e não deram o motivo. A idéia é legal, não sabia de `data-url`....

Answer (score 0):

Bem, você pode usar uma requisição ajax para o cadastro (Form), onde o retorno desse ajax será a lista da tabela atualizada, assim apenas será preciso atualizar os campos da tabela com o retorno do ajax.